# Performance Monitor Unit(PMU) data save

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm

I am trying to calculate clock cycles of an assembly program consumed during execution through PMU in ARM1176JZF-S.
I am programming rapberry pi model b in assembly using baking-pi tutorials. The code for PMU that I am using is as below:

/* Enable PMU */ 
  mov r0,#1 
  MCR p15, 0, r0, c15, c12, 0 ; Write Performance Monitor Control Register 
  /* Reset Cycle Counter */ 
  mov r0,#5 
  MCR p15, 0, r0, c15, c12, 0 ; Write Performance Monitor Control Register 
  /* Meaure */ 
  MRC p15, 0, r0, c15, c12, 1 @ Read Cycle Counter Register 
   
  MRC p15, 0, r1, c15, c12, 1 @ Read Cycle Counter Register 
  sub r0.r1.r0                @ Cycle Count of

Is there any way I can save this data in a text or csv file on my SD card (value of r0)? so I can view my results after code execution.

Comment: Simplest way is probably to use a C wrapper (i.e. providing main()) around your assembler code, calls assembly code as a function call, returns the cycle counts, write the results from C.

Comment: Of course there's a way; the fact that existing OSes can write files to the SD card is hard to miss... You just need to implement a driver for the SD host controller so you can get raw data on and off the card, then implement a filesystem driver to handle that data and manipulate it at the "file" level. The scope of that, though, is _way_ beyond "a few paragraphs" to make it answerable here.

Comment: Alternatively, rather than trying to save it anywhere, consider just dumping the data over the UART to a serial terminal on another machine.

Comment: Can you share any example?

Comment: same answer as in the raspberry pi forums.  bare metal access to the sd card is not trivial, there are libraries, but if you are wanting to play with dozens of instructions and save results, and needing thousands of lines of code to save those results.  doesnt make sense.  either bare metal a print routine, or just use jtag and dump the registers out.

Comment: You are right this seems like a better and simple approach. Can you please share any example, (or any informative link) so I start understand its working.

Comment: For most UARTs, you can implement a polling-mode `putchar` in 4 instructions (loop on the status until it's clear then write the data), you just need to check the docs for the relevant register offsets and status bits. Then, writing a routine to print a 32-bit value as hex characters is, in my opinion, a really fun exercise (I think the best I've got it down to in the past is 10 instructions); or you could cheat and write it in C.